# Replace contents of a div upon clicking a link

Tags: html

Well I would reproduce in a html page this scenario. I have a div in a html page and inside this div I have two links.When I clink one of those links the div change but without changing the entire web page.How could I realize it?

Comment: This type of behavior is usually realized with JavaScript. Get a book on this topic, it's very interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jquery:

```
<div id="changeMe">
 <p id="changeThis">You have some stuff here</p>
 <a href="#" id="changeLink">Click to change</a>
</div>

<script>
$('#changeLink').click(function(){
  $('#changeThis').html('I am the new text');
  return false;
});
</script>
```

see it run here http://jsfiddle.net/G9MgN/

> Remember, to use this method you will need jquery called in your

```
> <head></head>
```

You can do that using Google's service

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```